# How to set a value of a property of a nested item in order to make it visible via *ngIf directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a component to reuse the mat-progress-spinner from angular material. I need this in order to avoid putting for every single page the same code. Here is the code that is working:

```
<div id="overlayProgressSpinner">
    <div class="center">
    <mat-progress-spinner
        style="margin:0 auto;"
        mode="indeterminate"
        diameter="100"
        *ngIf="loading">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is simple. Only to set "loading" as true or false.
What did I do?

I put above code inside a custom component. Now it is like so:

```
<app-progress-spinner></app-progress-spinner>
```

its HTML code is the same and its TS code is as a follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-spinner',
  templateUrl: './progress-spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-spinner.component.scss']
})
export class ProgressSpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public isLoading(value: boolean) {
    this.loading = value;

  }

  public changeSpinnerCSSClass() {
    const htmlDivElement = (window.document.getElementById('overlayProgressSpinner') as HTMLDivElement);
    if (this.loading) {
      htmlDivElement.className = 'overlay';
    } else {
      htmlDivElement.className = '';
    }
  }

}
```

when the property "loading" belongs to the current component, I can show and hide the "mat-progress-spinner" component. Otherwise, when it belongs to "app-progress-spinner" it is set but it is not being displayed. The code that I am trying to make it visible is as follows:

```
          this.progressSpinner.isLoading(false); // it is set, but it does not work.
          this.progressSpinner.changeSpinnerCSSClass(); // it works
```

it appears that *ngIf="loading" cannot be set by using the approach the works if the logic behind belongs to the current component.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `input` in your `ProgressSpinnerComponent`. To do that, add the `@Input()` decorator before the property `loading`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-spinner',
  templateUrl: './progress-spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-spinner.component.scss']
})
export class ProgressSpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() loading = false;
```

So anywhere you need to use the `app-progress-spinner` you do:

```
<app-progress-spinner [loading]="loading"></app-progress-spinner>
```

**Note:** The `loading` variable assigned to the *input* `loading` belongs to the component that contains the`app-progress-spinner`.

This happens because every component have it own scope, meaning that it have no access to external world unless you create an `input` or `output` in order to receive or send data. There's also the ngModel that can be used for bi-diretional data, but not recommend in most cases.

Comment: thanks. it compiled, but when I try to set it as true or false nothing happens. How to do so in a way to make it visible or hidden?

Comment: You don't need to use the isLoading() method, actually it won't work. You need to change the loading state by modifying the loading input value. Using `<app-progress-spinner [loading]="true"></app-progress-spinner>` should show a progress spinner. If doesn't, you need to double check your code for something wrong.

Comment: yes. I founded the problem. I was trying to update to change the property's value of the parent component directly, not using its property value with a decorator. Your answer could be reviewed in order to make clear that  "loading" variable of "app-progress-spinner" declaration is from the current component, not from the parent one. I got it. Thank you!